# Passing data to Laravel event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I've just started to read about `events` in laravel and have been stuck for a few hours now. This may be very easy but I'm missing something.

I fire the event like this

```
// get the referrer
$referrer = Customer::where('promocode', $user->referral_code)->first();

// fire referral sign up event
Event::fire(new ReferralSignupEvent($referrer));
```

As you can see I'm passing an `eloquent` object to the event.

I create the event;

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Customer;

class ReferralSignupEvent extends Event
{

    public $referrer;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Customer $referrer)
    {
        //
        $this->referrer = $referrer;
    }
}
```

I create the listener

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ReferralSignupEvent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EmailReferralSignupConfirmation
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ReferralSignupEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ReferralSignupEvent $event)
    {
        //
        $referrer = $event->referrer;

        $mailer = app()->make('mailer');

        $mailer->queue('emails.restaurant-welcome', ['referrer' => $referrer] , function ($message) use ($referrer) {
            $message->from('support@xxxx.com', 'xxx Restaurant Team');
            $message->subject('Welcome to xxx');
            $message->to($referrer->email)->bcc('support@xxx.com');
        });
    }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck, how can I access the `customer` I passed to the event and access it's attributes like `email, first_name` etc
I also need to pass it to my email template to gain access to those attributes to personalise the email.

I'm getting an error on this line `$referrer->email`

`field email not found in class`

Any help appreciated

This is what I get from `dd($referrer)`

```
object(App\Models\Customer)#79 (23) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  string(3) "web"
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(9) "customers"
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "email"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "first_name"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "last_name"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "mobile_phone"
    [5]=>
    string(13) "address_line1"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "address_line2"
    [7]=>
    string(13) "address_line3"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "token"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "vcode"
    [10]=>
    string(9) "promocode"
    [11]=>
    string(14) "referral_count"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "verified"
    [13]=>
    string(11) "location_id"
    [14]=>
    string(7) "city_id"
  }
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(19) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(8) "Abubakar"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(8) "Mohammed"
    ["email"]=>
    string(21) "xxx@gmail.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$22iIZu7lvzjiNjxN4c6g6Ov1NCBmfSypVQ4RoL20qL4M5YqvAz/vS"
    ["mobile_phone"]=>
    string(11) "07427356289"
    ["address_line1"]=>
    string(17) "25 Hamilton House"
    ["address_line2"]=>
    string(8) "Lonsdale"
    ["address_line3"]=>
    string(9) "Wolverton"
    ["city"]=>
    NULL
    ["vcode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["promocode"]=>
    string(8) "XXXXXXXX"
    ["referral_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["token"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$22iIZu7lvzjiNjxN4c6g6OqJ.Hzr67xYdJj34w4XXkW2e_ioVv1Si"
    ["verified"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-29 00:05:52"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-11 17:42:15"
    ["city_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["location_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(19) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(8) "Abubakar"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(8) "Mohammed"
    ["email"]=>
    string(21) "xxx@gmail.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$22iIZu7lvzjiNjxN4c6g6Ov1NCBmfSypVQ4RoL20qL4M5YqvAz/vS"
    ["mobile_phone"]=>
    string(11) "07427356289"
    ["address_line1"]=>
    string(17) "25 Hamilton House"
    ["address_line2"]=>
    string(8) "Lonsdale"
    ["address_line3"]=>
    string(9) "Wolverton"
    ["city"]=>
    NULL
    ["vcode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["promocode"]=>
    string(8) "XXXXXXXX"
    ["referral_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["token"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$22iIZu7lvzjiNjxN4c6g6OqJ.Hzr67xYdJj34w4XXkW2e_ioVv1Si"
    ["verified"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-29 00:05:52"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-11 17:42:15"
    ["city_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["location_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["morphClass":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I just want to be able to access the attributes.

Comment: can you `dd($referrer)` in the handle method?

Comment: @JilsonThomas I doubt I can see the dump if I do that since it's not a view

Comment: You can see the output in the network tab if you inspect with Chrome.

Comment: True.. but it's hard to test as I've coded the process end to end yet

Comment: There is nothing special about the view which says you can only output items in the view besides best practices.  You can `dd` anywhere and it will work just the same.

Comment: I've updated the question with my `dd` guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a code error. Your code should work fine. This is just an issue with your IDE. Because of the way field attributes work on Eloquent models, your IDE has no idea that the `email` field actually does exist, so it reports it as missing.

The [`barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package may help with this issue.

In addition to the above package, providing a proper PHPDoc for your `public $referrer;` attribute may help, as well.

```
class ReferralSignupEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * The customer referrer.
     *
     * @var \App\Models\Customer
     */
    public $referrer;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: @moh.ABK Looks fine to me. Especially since your `dd()` showed the `Customer` object.